# TKinter - Buttong with image does flickers and has background

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have this button image "order.png". Firstly it did not want to be opened by tkinter so I had to use pillow, and now I am getting this white flickering background when i run the program. Does anyone how to fix this?

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk 
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()
window.config(bg="black")
window.title("V1")

img= (Image.open("./01_V1/01_MainUI//Order.png"))
resized_image= img.resize((300,300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)


order_button = tk.Button(image=new_image, relief='flat',borderwidth=0, bg="black")
order_button.grid(column=1, row=1)



window.mainloop()
```

It should look like a normal png with no borders as the button

Comment: Do you mean the gray background? It can't be removed as tkinter widget does not support transparent background.

Comment: It's probably a problem with your image. Check if your image has gray borders.

Comment: @z3nox. Are you using macosx?